# fall silent vs. remain silent

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Someone told me "fall silent" is an observation. "Remain silent" is a choice.

Example:

> Mary fell silent for a few seconds. (Here we are observing Mary's
> action)
>
> Mary remained silent for a few seconds. (Here we're showing Mary's decision)

Is this correct? Or do the two sentences imply the same thing?

Comment: Both falling and remaining silent can be an observation or a choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation that you received doesn't make sense to me.

*Falling* silent is going from a state of not being silent to a state of being silent.

*Remaining* silent is what is sounds like - i.e., continuing to be silent.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence shows how Mary went from making noise to *becoming* silent, which shows the action of her falling silent and her choice/decision of being silent.

The second sentence shows her *remaining* silent, showing her choice of making no sound, but yes there is not really an action here that Mary made, but some may view "remaining silent" as an action. Either way both sentences imply different meanings.

Comment: We do not know that she was 'making noise'; we only know that she was producing _sound_. Most likely she was speaking, although I suppose singing was possible, or a mixture.

Comment: If she was shouting, screaming, ululating, etc, then maybe she was 'making [a] noise'.